# Passing a variable into a models after_initialize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, model, will-paginate

I have the following (heavily simplified) model, that uses will_paginate

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_reader :articles

  def after_initialize
    @articles = Article.paginate_by_name name, :page => 1
  end

end
```

and the controller code in my show action is

```
@search = Search.new(params[:search])
```

This all works fine, but notice i hard coded the page number to 1, problem is passing params[:page] value into the after_initialize method, can anyone suggest an elegant way to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a page parameter (or even better an options hash parameter) to the initialize method:

```
class Search
  def initialize(search, options = {})
    @options = options
  end

  def after_initialize
    @articles = Article.paginate_by_name name, :page => @options[:page]
  end
end
```

and then in your controller:

```
@search = Search.new(params[:search], :page => params[:page])
```

You can even supply default values to the option hash, if you like.

Comment: As `Search` extends `ActiveRecord::Base` remember to include the call to `super(search)` and to make `search` an optional parameter too i.e. `def initialize(search = {}, options = {})` in order to preserve existing behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for help, all working now. Small gotcha, be sure to put the call to super after assignment of the options, as super will trigger after_initialize callback.